# Create Test Data in Code

Tags: c#

I am writing an exporting function to take data from a database table and export to text.  Before I plug the code into the rest of the app I would like to test the export based on random data created in c#.  I have found many examples in SO about creating test data in a database but none that was created directly in code.  Does anybody have an example or know of a link to one?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [AutoFixture](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture) to generate pseudo-random data directly from C# code.

It is a convention-based and extensible library that uses reflection to populate objects with data.

It can be used as simply as this:

```
Fixture fixture = new Fixture();
MyClass mc = fixture.CreateAnonymous<MyClass>();
```

After the second line of code, the `mc` instance will be populated with all appropiate constructor parameters, and all writable properties will have been assigned.

It supports nested hierachies, non-default constructors, mapping from interfaces to concrete types and many other things.

You can customize it (almost) to your heart's content as well.

Comment: @Mark - Looks good.  Can AutoFixture create random numbers instead of incremental?

Comment: Yes, that would require you to first customize the Fixture instance like this: `fixture.Register<int>(() => r.Next());` where `r` is an instance of a randowm number generator (such as System.Random).

Answer (score 0):

You can try [NBuilder](http://code.google.com/p/nbuilder/) if you haven't already.